# How can i store a list within a numpy 2d array?

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, numpy

How can i store a list within a numpy 2d array?

```
import numpy  
A = numpy.empty([5,5], dtype=**?**)
```

What should be the dtype for a variable list kind of thing here? or Is there a different way to implement this, which I strongly feel would be the case.

Comment: I don't get this.  How is this supposed to be a two-dimensional array?

Comment: I changed it to numpy.empty([x,y]). I just want to be able to store a list into say a position [a,b]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
>>> input = numpy.array(range(10))
>>> data = numpy.zeros((2,2), dtype=numpy.ndarray)
>>> data[1][1] = input
>>> data
    array([[0, 0],
          [0, [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]]], dtype=object)
```