# Initialize multidimensional array in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I am moving from c to python.

I want to initialize an array of different lengths: `map((2,3,(5,6,7)))`

I want each entry of an array `np.zeros((2,3))` to be a list with different lengths.

I would like the python equivalent to the c:

```
for(ii=0; ii<N; ii++) {
    dim[ii] = ii**2;
    for(jj=0; jj<Z; jj++) {
        map[jj][ii] = (long*) calloc(dim[ii], sizeof(long));
    }
}
```

I've tried several things but none is what I need. I would like to access later to the data easily and with lists I haven't managed to.

Thanks!

Comment: `np.zeros` needs a defined size, so you can not (as far as I know) use that with a variable length. Can you just create a list of lists with different lengths? Is this used in something computationally heavy?

Comment: [Maybe relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229897/how-can-i-store-a-list-within-a-numpy-2d-array).

Comment: I'm a not a C guy, can you add an overview of the desired output array within ` n=2 and z=3` or some random `n` and `z` ?

Comment: I tried with a list of lists but then I have problems accesing the data. The lengths of the arrays are big (12*4096*4096) the largest list.  The desired output would be: map=[ [[0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]] , [[0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]] ]

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do it:

```
>>> x=[[0]*3 for count in range(2)]
>>> for ii in range(2):
...     for jj in range(3):
...         x[ii][jj]=[0]*(jj+1)**2
... 
>>> x
[[[0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]]
```

Although I'm sure there is a better way, Thank you!